# Custom FileUpload

Tags: flask-appbuilder

I'm using flask-appbuilder to upload CSV files and then run some actions based on these files.

I need to have a FileColumn with some specific features:
* Checking the format of the uploaded CSV file
* Sorting the file before storing it's reference in the DB column

I think this will require defining a new custom FileColumn by overriding some methods, but I can't really find what classes to override.

Has anyone already done such things ?
Can someone point me to the steps and classes I need to override ?

Thanks in advance